# How should I configure my tasks.json file to compile multiple .cpp files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17

I tried the option below in my **tasks.json** file:

```
"args": [
            "-g",
            "${fileDirname}\\*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ]
```

It didn't work. I also tried `${workspaceFolder}` instead of `${fileDirname}` but it didn't work either. I know that I can add **.cpp** files manually to my **tasks.json** file but I don't want to hardcode it. Is there another option that could work ?

---

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.hpp"

void display_active_players() {
    std::cout << "Active players: " << Player::get_num_players() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    display_active_players();
    Player hero {"Hero"};
    display_active_players();

    {
        Player frank {"Frank"};
        display_active_players();
    }
    display_active_players();

    Player *enemy = new Player {"Enemy", 100, 100};
    display_active_players();
    delete enemy;
    display_active_players();

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.hpp"

int Player::num_players {0};

Player::Player(std::string name_val, int health_val, int xp_val) 
    : name {name_val}, health {health_val}, xp {xp_val} {
        num_players++;
}

Player::Player(const Player &source) 
    : Player {source.name, source.health, source.xp} {
}

Player::~Player() {
    num_players--;
}

int Player::get_num_players() {
    return num_players;
}
```

**Player.hpp**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <string>

class Player {
    private:
        static int num_players;
        std::string name;
        int health;
        int xp;
    public:
        std::string get_name() { return name; }
        int get_health() { return health; }
        int get_xp() { return xp; }
        Player(std::string name_val = "None", int health_val = 0, int xp_val = 0);
        // Copy constructor
        Player(const Player &source);
        // Destructor
        ~Player();
        static int get_num_players();
};

#endif
```

Here is the error when I try to compile:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `Player::get_num_players()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `Player::Player(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `Player::Player(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `Player::Player(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x24a): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\miami\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUfdvjk.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x28d): undefined reference to `Player::~Player()'
collect2.exe: hata: ld ��k�� durumu 1 ile d�nd�
```

Answer (score 0):

VSCode's "tasks" system is not a build system, it's supposed to run an external build system, not the compiler directly. You should decide on an actual build system (such as CMake, make, msbuild, etc.) for your project and configure it appropriately, then configure VSCode to run it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stu . I also added my code now if you would like to see it.